# Find unique values in a list of type string and then convert the original list to a numerical equivalent

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list of type string

```
a = ["green","green","blue","red","yellow","blue","green","red"]
```

and lets also suppose that there is a function I already have such that it returns the unique values in that list. So for the above list the result is:

```
unique_a = ["green","blue","red","yellow"]
```

How do I first convert the list `unique_a` into a numerical equivalent, ie, (Note that the order matters)

```
unique_a_int = [1,2,3,4]
```

and then convert list `a` into the corresponding numerical equivalent such that,

```
a_int = [1,1,2,3,4,2,1,3]
#1 represents green
#2 represents blue
#3 represents red
#4 represents yellow
```

If there is a much better way to convert `a` to `a_int` I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension with `enumerate`, then map it:

```
a = ["green","green","blue","red","yellow","blue","green","red"]

unique_a = ["green","blue","red","yellow"]

x = {item:num for num, item in enumerate(unique_a,1)}

result = list(map(x.get, a))

print (result)

#[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3]
```